# Counting the number of items added in LookUp column

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I have a `lookup Column` in my `list` which can take multiple values. So I need to count the total number of items added in that lookup field.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: using what js or c#?

Comment: using js or OOB things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in comment that JS solution will do for your. So make a GET request to the the list and `$expand` the lookup column. Let's lookup column's name is `Department`

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items?$select=Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department
```

In response, you will get an array of Departments. Like

```
"Department": {
      "results": [
        {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "0e5b6244-0d4a-40d4-a8c6-d125a2ae7e9b",
            "type": "SP.Data.ParentListItem"
          },
          "Title": "B"
        },
        {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "96abb8a2-151a-4da3-b0b6-fdcff2a2aa51",
            "type": "SP.Data.ParentListItem"
          },
          "Title": "C"
        },
        {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "b74c8509-7a87-4c55-8b87-c8c4693065e6",
            "type": "SP.Data.ParentListItem"
          },
          "Title": "D"
        }
      ]
    }
```

So total number of  items added in that lookup field are `Department.results.length`

Using [JSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694749/sharepoint-2013-multivalue-lookup-field-with-javascript)

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.getItemById(1);   
context.load(listItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
       var lookupVals = listItem.get_item(fieldName); //get multi lookup value (SP.FieldLookupValue[])
       var totalLookupVals = lookupVals.length;
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

Let me know for more explanation or modification.

Comment: Now if I have to insert this value of `totalLookupVals ` to the same item in a new column then can we do it using rest

Comment: will it work for `data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.HpListListItem' }, 
         'gb3c': totalLookupVals}),`

Comment: I could not get...

Comment: I want to enter the value `totalLookupVals` in another column in same list

Comment: Then it should work? make sure `SP.Data.HpListListItem` is the valid `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` and `gb3c` is the valid internal name

Comment: it shows error `cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'edm.string'`

Comment: Need to see the code. Ask it in an another question. I will try to help

Comment: I needed to convert it to string...

Comment: Issue solved? ....

Comment: yes but the value is now coming as a new item in list, I need to get it in the same row..

Comment: So your can `$filter` it for your desired row.

Answer (score 2):

I used JSLink in the listview to retrieve this field, which comes back in the context object as an array. I then use the length property to render the count to the field I want.

Note that this is only good for view purposes as JS link does not actually update the value of the field itself, unless you explicitly write code to do so.

Steps are:

1. Create a js script file eg: "lookupcount.js" somewhere, like your style library.
2. In your listview webpart properties, under miscellaneous, you'll find a place to reference your JSLink. [image]
3. In your javascript file, use the following code. NOTE: FieldToUpdate and LookUpField should be changed to your field names.

   ```
   (function () { 

   var priorityFiledContext = {}; 
   priorityFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
   priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
       // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
       "FieldToUpdate": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate } 
   }; 

       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext); 

   })();
   ```

   function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {

   var lookupfield = ctx.CurrentItem.LookUpField;
      var number = lookupfield.length;
      ctx.CurrentItem.FieldToUpdate;
      var returnRowStyle = "" + ctx.CurrentItem.FieldToUpdate + "";
      return returnRowStyle;
   }